# How to return an instance of a class from a function, within the class?

Tags: c++

In this exercise I'm supposed to create a priority queue class backed by a vector. This code works except for the Merge function at the end. How to create a new instance of the class from one and two, and return an instance of the class?

```
 #include "pqueue-vector.h"
    #define PR(x) cout << #x " = " << x << "\n";
    using namespace std;

    VectorPQueue::VectorPQueue() {
        Vector<string> pQueue;
    }

    VectorPQueue::~VectorPQueue() {

    }

    string VectorPQueue::peek() const {
        if(isEmpty()) {
            error("peek; Attempting to peek at an empty queue");
        }
        string result = pQueue.get(0);
        return result;
    }

    string VectorPQueue::extractMin() {
        if (isEmpty()) {
            error("extractmin; Queue is empty");
        }
        int min = 0;
        string minimum = pQueue.get(0);
        for (int i= 1; i < logSize; i++) {
            string check = pQueue.get(i);
            if (check < minimum) {
                min = i;
                minimum = check;
            }
        }
        pQueue.remove(min);
        logSize--;
        return minimum;
    }

    void VectorPQueue::enqueue(const string& elem) {
        pQueue.add(elem);
        logSize++;
    }


    VectorPQueue *VectorPQueue::merge(VectorPQueue *one, VectorPQueue *two) {

        VectorPQueue result;
        for (int i = 0; i < one->size(); i++) {
        string test1 = one->extractMin();
        string test2 = two->extractMin();

                result.enqueue(test1);
                result.enqueue(test2);
            }
        // placeholder so method compiles..
        // replace with your own implementation
        return new VectorPQueue result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I won't solve this for you, but will give you a hint.

The outline should be as follows:

```
VectorPQueue *VectorPQueue::merge(VectorPQueue *one, VectorPQueue *two) {
    VectorPQueue* result = new VectorPQueue;
    // TODO: populate *result
    return result;
}
```

Comment: @RobbieCooper, why can't you just return a copy?

Comment: ..after changing enqueue to result->enqueue(test1); etc